# Как правильно составить MySQL запрос с прибавлением времени?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица, в которой хранится время в формате "TIME". Есть другая таблица, в которой хранятся другие данные "TIME". Необходим запрос, который будет получать оттуда данные из первой таблицы, исключая данные из второй, при этом данные из второй таблицы должны браться с учетом сдвига в N-минут.
Пытался сделать так,

`$interval = date('H:i:s',strtotime('00:30'));
    $begin_time_data = $mysqli->query("SELECT time FROM times WHERE time NOT IN (SELECT ch_time FROM events)+$interval");`

но получаю пустой результат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL сам умеет вычислять интервалы времени с помощью конструкции interval. А вот складывать с непосредственными значениями (будь то секунды или строка времени, полученная date() в php), без использования interval тяжело. Кроме того сложение результата подзапроса со значением предполагает, что такой подзапрос должен вернуть только одну строку, что не сочетается с NOT IN, который ожидает множество строк. Подзапрос NOT IN должен вернуть уже готовые для использования данные, а следовательно сложение надо произвести прямо в нем.

```
SELECT time FROM times
 WHERE time NOT IN (SELECT ch_time + interval 30 minute FROM events)
```

Comment: *А вот работать с секундами ему тяжело* ???  В смысле? точность типа TIME - микросекунда. Если указать, конечно. *при сложении time 23:59 с интервалом в 30 минут получаем 00:29.* ?? [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=780db0cf441aaeef5f59f5340c8d639b). *With the fractional part included, the range for TIME values is '-838:59:59.000000' to '838:59:59.000000'.*

Comment: @Akina Спасибо, я как то криво видимо проверял, увидел 00 часов. Под первым предложением имел ввиду, что time нельзя оператором + складывать с секундами или со строкой '00:30:00'

Comment: *time нельзя оператором + складывать с секундами* Просто с секундами нельзя, а с интервалом в секундах (`'10:00' + INTERVAL 123 SECOND`) - запросто.